# the status of the md-checkbox in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have this `md-checkbox` element :

```
<md-checkbox (change)="showPaidOrders($event)">
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'paid' | translate}}</span>
</md-checkbox>
```

and its `TS` implementation :

```
showPaidOrders(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      return true;
    }   
}
```

Why it is consoling

> cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

it is working on the ordianry `input` element in its `checkbox` type , is there any alternative to check constantly (**on every click**) the status of the `md-checkbox` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/535

md-checkbox doesn't support checked. If you feel it's necessary you can
submit a pull request that updates the directive scope to accept
ng-checked/checked as an attribute and pass that value when present onto
the input within the directive template.

but there is workaround

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="truthy" ng-checked="true" label="md-checkbox">{{truthy}}</md-checkbox>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RKwM5mRYLh5k6MoAyLnS?p=preview

Comment: Good , a question before , what is the main purpose of `ng-checked` , if I remove it, it still working ?

Comment: it is only for initial status of checkbox :)

Comment: hhh , I've just said 'before' i.e : before accepting the answer .. Ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `event.checked` instead of `event.target.checked`. `<md-checkbox>` uses its own change, not the regular `<checkbox>`'s. Take a look at `MdCheckboxChange`.